# Why am I NOT getting C4192 when importing msxml6?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

We been instructed to eliminate all level 3 warnings and have been specifically told to address C4192.

My code does fall into the "bad code" example that causes C4192

```
#import "msxml6.dll" named_guids
```

and the "good code" is easy enough to implement

```
#import "msxml6.dll" exclude("ISequentialStream","_FILETIME")named_guids
```

The only problem, is that I just do not get this warning.  I'm importing version 6.30.7601.18431 of msxml6.dll, and no matter what I do, this warning just does not manifest.

I also imported it again, specifying the no_auto_exclude option and could find no reference to ISequentialStream or _FILETIME in the generated tli and tlh files.

I'm about to simply update to use the "good" code and go on, but I'd still like to know what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specifically an issue because new version of MSXML6.0 changed declarations , especially from Win10 OS onwards.

We already encountered this warning message with our legacy code base having 'bad code' , which you mentioned in your question.

In your case, your system is having  older version of MSXML6.DLL (present in "C:\Windows\System32 or SysWow64").

Hope this calrifies your query.

Comment: Outstanding!  This would also explain why some received this warning (otherwise, why would I be instructed to remove it) and I (and my fellow developers) did not.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)